# Android view pager not populating views fragments

Tags: android

I have a master/detail view to display my users. The member detail fragment contains swipe tabs to go between 3 other fragments - message, profile and photos (in that order, the middle tab is activated by default).

When I open the master/detail view on a tablet and click on the first user, all the fragments are correctly created.

However, when I then click on another user, the 'detail' fragment containing the swipe tabs is correctly created, but all of the fragments within it are empty, and none of the callbacks within any of the fragments in the tabs are called. It seems that the SectionsPagerAdapter isn't instantiating the fragments except for the first time it's created.

Debugging, I've found that my SectionsPagerAdapter is definitely being called in my 'detail' fragment:

```
            Log.d(CLS, "Creating the ViewPager");
            // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
            // primary sections of the app.
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

However, getItem on my SectionsPagerAdapter is only ever called for the first user. It always calls SectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle correctly though.

More code:

```
/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    // The IDs of the strings to show for each tab 
    private int[] tabStringIDs = new int[]{
        R.string.message,
        R.string.profile,
        R.string.photos
    };

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle args = null;
        Log.d(CLS, "SectionsPagerAdapter.getItem called for position: " + position);

        switch (position) {
        case 0:                     // message thread
            Log.d(CLS, "Adding fragment for position: " + position);

            fragment = new MessageDetailFragment();
            args = new Bundle();
            // TODO: Set the user ID properly (for the ID of the user the message thread is between)
            String otherUserId = "123453124aaaa";
            args.putString(MessageDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, otherUserId);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            break;
        case 1:                     // profile
            fragment = new UserDetailProfileFragment();
            userDetailFragment = (UserDetailProfileFragment)fragment;
            if (mItem != null) {
                Log.d(CLS, "Setting userDetailFragment user object in getItem()");
                ((UserDetailProfileFragment)fragment).setUser(mItem);
            }
            break;
        case 2:                     // image grid
            fragment = new UserDetailPhotoListFragment();
            photoListFragment = (UserDetailPhotoListFragment)fragment;
            if (mItem != null) {
                Log.d(CLS, "Setting photoListFragment user object in getItem()");
                photoListFragment.setUser(mItem);
            }
            break;
        } 

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabStringIDs.length;  
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Log.d(CLS, "SectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle called for position: " + position);
        try {
            return getString(tabStringIDs[position]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(CLS, "Caught an exception accessing the pager title: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know wny my fragments are blank/not being created?

If I scroll around between the tabs, the furthest one away from me is paused and then when it is restored the data is correctly displayed.

Basically I'm looking for a way of forcing the fragment manager to reinstantiate it's fragments - or at least call one of the callback methods on them.

### Update

This only affects my two pane master/detail view. On smaller devices where a new activity is launched to display the profiles, it all works. Maybe it's something to do with how I'm handling switching detail views. Here's the click hander in my user list activity:

```
    @Override
public void onUserItemSelected(String id, String title) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        Log.d(CLS, "Creating new user detail fragment for two-pane mode for user ID: " + id);
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(UserDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        UserDetailFragment fragment = new UserDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments); 
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.user_detail_container, fragment).commit();

    } else {
        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, UserDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(UserDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        Log.d(CLS, "Adding item title " + title + " to bundle");
        detailIntent.putExtra(UserDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_TITLE, title);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code? I think that maybe is because the ViewPager have a cache of pages, when you move to a certain position the ViewPager calls the getItem in the forward and backward positions where you are.

Comment: I've added my SectionsPagerAdapter. There definitely seems to be a fragment cache involved somewhere, but it's not even displaying the previous person's data when I click on a different user - all the fragments are just blank. It's only when I scroll around that the fragements get created.

Comment: try this, in the onClick (when you click an user) make sure that you are setting again the adapter `mViewPager.setAdapter(new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());` I saw this kind of errors before, the Fragments will not be re created  unless you explicity call setAdapter with a new adapter.

Comment: Isn't that the same as my first code block above? The log line does get executed, so I know it's being called...

Comment: Have you solved this? you are passing ARG_ITEM_TITLE into your intent for single-pane, but not bundle for two-pane, is that significant? also be sure you are loading from both the intent received by the activity and the bundle received by the fragment.